# Extract files from instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm making a project where I create a network and launch instances in it to interact with each other.There will be some tasks that the users will have to make in their instance and then i need to extract a file from a defined path from that instance. I have read that it is possible, but i cant find the way to do it nor information about it.

Im using the OpenStack API to make the project and I cant find any request to do so.

Does anyone have any clue about this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no openstack api to extract files from an instance: you need to use the same tools (e.g., `scp`, `rsync`, etc) that you would use with any other internet connected host.

Comment: You could also just mount some form of network storage (e.g. NFS) within the instances so you don't need to copy or extract anything.